# Diet coke chicken recipe safe when heating the artificial sweetener contained in the diet coke during the boiling process?

Tags: food-safety

I'm on the Atkins induction week, which means my food choices are limited. One of the recipes I found suggested a recipe which involved Diet Coke chicken. Which basically is boiling chicken in diet coke.

Since I want to try something new, I was all open for the idea, but then I was wondering if it's safe considering you would be heating up the sugar replacement in the diet coke (my case is pepsi max)?

Comment: Note that nutrition is off topic here. The question is on-topic as a food safety question, that is, we can tell you (if somebody knows it) whether it can happen that you are delivered in hospital with acute heat-degraded-sweetener poisoning or not. Long-term health effects (for example, if it is a suspected carcinogen) are off topic.

Comment: @rumtscho modified the question to focus a bit more on safety and make it more specific

Comment: Thank you. Independently of any on- and off-topic considerations, more specific titles are better, they allow others to know at a glance what a question is about. So I like your edit. Else my comment was not meant to make you change the question, just an information so you'd know what information you can get here and what kind we cannot supply, so you can decide whether to look about it elsewhere.

Comment: @rumtscho are long term health effects from an ingredient or method  that is scientifically accepted to be deleterious (eg, things where  governmental or academic institutions recommend you limit consumption to a certain amount) also OT here?

Comment: !rackandboneman yes, they are also off topic. The whole "don't eat that because it's bad for you" set of beliefs about food is off topic here, no matter who promotes it - government, scientists, or self-proclaimed gurus. What we allow is the food safety part, as in prevention of infections or cases of poisoning which are potentially traceable to a single meal, and in this case, we want the objective government mandated guidelines of safety and not the personal intuitive decision of "I'd eat it" or "I ate a similar thing and didn't get sick". But RDAs are OT.

Comment: I don't believe heating regular coke is safe, either, honestly. Coke, or any soft drink, is quite a complicated mixture. It will be really nice to have the manufacture's guarantee that the current and future ingredient will not degrade into toxins when heated to a certain temperature.  One of my concerns is the acid in the coke could corrode the cookware and dissolve some metal into the food.